# Failed Unit Test

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have a service for adding city in DB. It works good, now I need test it. I have never worked with tests before. I'll be grateful for your recommendations. I would test case - If it isn't null - test passed(I mean if User insert anything - test is passed, if he doesn't insert data - test failed). I need just check townName null or no. It is my TestClass

```
   [TestClass]
    public partial class TownRepositoryTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task InsertTownName_ReturnTownName()
        {
            var builder = new RepositoryBuilder<TownRepository>().SetupManager();

            using (builder.CreateIsolationScope())
            {
               var expectedTown = await TestBuilder.SetupTownNameAsync(builder);

                var repository = builder.Build();

                var townName = expectedTown.Name;

                var result = await repository.InsertTown(townName);

                Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

SetupTownNameAsync method(here I add data). I think it works good, because when I used debug test, I checked that this method return (id=1, name= "TestTown")

```
       public static class TestBuilder
       {
           public static async Task<Town> SetupTownNameAsync(RepositoryBuilder<TownRepository> builder)
           {
               var town = await builder.CreateTownAsync(name: "TestTown");

               var setupResult = new Town
               {
                   Id = town.Id,
                   Name = town.Name 
               };

               return setupResult;
           }
       }
```

And here my InsertTown method

```
        public async Task<int> InsertTown(string townName)
        {
            var parameters = new { townName };

            return await Connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>(Adhoc["AddTown"], parameters, Transaction);
        }
```

When I checked problem with debug test - in this line returns "TestTown", but when I check it in Assert - my test is failed

```
                var result = await repository.InsertTown(townName);

                Assert.IsNotNull(result);
```

Comment: _"I would test case - that in my field not null, then I'll add it in DB It is my TestClass"_ - I can't understand what you're trying to say with this. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: I can't see how your test could fail on `Assert.IsNotNull(result);`, by the way. It's very strange.

Comment: I changed it, sorry. 
Yeah, I think that it will works good, but test is failed.

Comment: What's the exact message you get with the test failure?

Comment: What value do you get in `result` ?

Comment: Test method innRoad.innSupportTools.Data.Tests.TownRepositoryTests.InsertTownName_ReturnTownName threw exception: 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An explicit value for the identity column in table 'town' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: I think I find a problem. After commit and pulling my local DB was deleted. It's very strange because it was automatically